# Ruby on Rails / Devise - Requiring password on email change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

This is it, for all the marbles, if I can get this issue solved then I have a project completed.

Anyway, I am using Ruby on Rails 3 with Devise for user authentication. As you may know, in the user admin/edit by default, a user has to enter their current password in the current_password field if they provide a new password. There is a TON of information out there on how to disable current_password so users can change and save freely.

However, I can find very little on doing the opposite: requiring the current password for more fields...in my case, the email field. AND only require the current password when that email addy is changed, not if it remains the same. Currently users can freely change their email without giving their current password, and for security reasons, I don't want this.

After looking through the Devise wiki, I did find [this page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) and I thought I could reverse this code to complete this solution. I managed to work this little bit out in my user.rb model (I stripped out of the unnecessary logic for this post)....

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :remember_me, :agree
  attr_accessor :accessible, :agree, :signed_in
  attr_readonly :name

  # Validation
  validates :name, :presence => TRUE, :uniqueness => TRUE, :length => { :within => 4..20 }
  validates :agree, :term_agreement => TRUE, :unless => :signed_in
  validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabyte
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
  validates :current_password, :presence => TRUE, :if => :password_required?

  protected

  def password_required?
    email_changed?
  end

end
```

It "almost" works. If I save the user profile with changing nothing, or change other non-password required field (like the user avatar), the profile saves fine, no password required. So far, so good.

And if I change the email address, the validation *is* triggered....but what happens is that both the current_password AND password (for new password) fields trigger as required. And if I fill in the password in all three (password, password_confirmation, current_password) just for the hell of it, it won't take, just gives a validation error again.

Basically, ONLY the current_password should be required if the email address is changed. How would I make this work in my code?

- UPDATE *******

I checked out my log in response to the below suggestion by bowsersenior, and see the following lines when I attempt to save and update the email...

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` WHERE (LOWER(`users`.`email`) = LOWER('newaddress@changed.com')) AND (`users`.id <> 1) LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`name` = BINARY 'Administrator') AND (`users`.id <> 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I wonder if that 'ROLLBACK' has something to do with the final issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
validates :current_password, :presence => TRUE, :if => :email_changed?
```

I strongly suggest you leave `password_required?` alone. That could lead to bugs with security and unstable behavior.

Comment: Closer yet, but not quite there. Now it does throw up an error on just the current password field - if not filled out - but what's odd is that even if you fill in the correct password, it spits out another "Current password can't be blank" error...which is strange.

Comment: I noticed something interesting in my log file which I can't currently interpret, I posted it following my original post above.

Comment: I think I know what's happening. Your model is not allowing `:current_password` to be set because you are protecting against mass assignment using `attr_accessible`. Try adding `:current_password` to the list of fields following `attr_accessible` . Can't tell you how many times I've been bitten by this issue!

Comment: I had suspected that also, though I didn't see the "can't update mass assigned" (or however it reads) message in there. I tried adding current_password into attr_accessible, but it still won't have it. I'm suspecting that "SELECT....WHERE(LOWER..." statement trying to select the new email address before the record is saved is throwing it off somehow. What's curious is if I remove the logic and make it work as normal, no select is attempted before the record is saved.

Comment: Nevermind, I *think* I solved it. I forgot to mention that I defined a seperate users_controller (outside of Devise's own) so I could have a seperate profile administration section for users to edit their own profile - outside of Devise's default user admin (intended for admin/staff users). Basically there was something in the users_controller that was removing current_password if the password was blank, long story short, it was interfering. So bowsersenior's answer is indeed correct. Thank you much.

Comment: Glad you got the problem solved. One note: in my experience mass assignment bugs tend to be invisible, so you have to be extra careful. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` causes similar headaches.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the Devise way of doing this is as follows:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    successfully_updated = if needs_password?(@user, params)
      @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    else
      # remove the virtual current_password attribute update_without_password
      # doesn't know how to ignore it
      params[:user].delete(:current_password)
      @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
    end

    if successfully_updated
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  def needs_password?(user, params)
    user.email != params[:user][:email]
  end
end
```

In other words, everything happens at the Controller level and we use either `User#update_with_password`, when user want to change his email (we know that by invoking `needs_password?` in the update action) or `User#update_without_password`, when user changes his other profile data.

Also remember you need to "register" this new RegistrationsController in your routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

Source:

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Pawel's answer, but rather than override the controller method update, how about this, based on the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if resource.email != params[:email] || params[:password].present?
      super
    else
      params.delete(:current_password)
      resource.update_without_password(params)
    end
  end
end
```